# Xcode Webview items not loading

Tags: swift, xcode, webview, loading

I have a Xcode Project with a **Webview** and a **TabBar** and with the TabBar I can switch between WebViews. My Problem is that when I put something in my ShoppingCard under [Lieferworld.de](https://lieferworld.de) and switch with the TabBar to my Shopping Card url the Items in there are not Visible. How can I solve this? the ShoppingCard URL ends with .php. Below is the code which is implemented

I also uploaded a video on YouTube were I you can see the error

https://youtu.be/qU3Mu1G7MY0

**Viewhome:**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class viewHome: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {



@IBOutlet var webViewHome: WKWebView!


 override func loadView() {
       let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
       webViewHome = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
       webViewHome.uiDelegate = self
       webViewHome.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
       //webViewHome.configuration.preferences.javaEnabled = true

       view = webViewHome

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "https://lieferworld.de")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webViewHome.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
    //webViewHome.configuration.preferences.javaEnabled = true
    webViewHome.load(request)
}




@IBAction func GoBackHome(_ sender: Any) {


    if webViewHome.canGoBack {

        webViewHome.goBack()

    }

}



@IBAction func GoForwardHome(_ sender: Any) {

    if webViewHome.canGoForward {

        webViewHome.goForward()

    }

}
```

}

**ViewShopping | Shopping Cart Class:**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class viewShopping: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {




@IBOutlet var webViewShopping: WKWebView!

override func loadView() {
       let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
       webViewShopping = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
       webViewShopping.uiDelegate = self
       //webViewShopping.configuration.preferences.javaEnabled = true
       webViewShopping.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true

       view = webViewShopping
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "https://lieferworld.de/warenkorb.php")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webViewShopping.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
    //webViewShopping.configuration.preferences.javaEnabled = true

    webViewShopping.load(request)
}

@IBAction func goBackShoppingCart(_ sender: Any) {

    if webViewShopping.canGoBack {

        webViewShopping.goBack()

    }

}


@IBAction func goForwardShoppingCart(_ sender: Any) {

if webViewShopping.canGoForward {

        webViewShopping.goForward()

    }

}


@IBAction func webViewRefresh(_ sender: Any) {

    webViewShopping.reload()
}

}
```

Comment: add WKNavigationDelegate to your class definition and implement the delegates.

Comment: I implemented WKNavigationDelegate but what do you mean with implement the the Delegates can you show me an example code?

BTW thank you so much for the Answer

Answer (score 1):

WKNavigationDelegate  has three delegates.

Here's an example;

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
 }
 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("Start page load")
 }
 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)
 {
    let title = webView.title
    print("finish  load. \(title).")
    // you can do processing on the results here or trigger processing elsewhere 
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()",completionHandler:
    { (html: Any?, error: Error?) in
                                  print(html as Any)
                                  self.htmlSource = html as! String
                                  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "pageLoaded"), object: nil)

    })
 }
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much, the problem is that I am a newbie in swift and I know it is unnecessary work for you but could write the code for me so that the things in my ShoppingCart are visible?

Comment: You should focus on managing the web pages. The shopping cart is not part of the web display function, it's back-end. Make sure that you can display pages properly first.